# TimeMachine migrates to the wrong date. How do I specifiy which date to migrate from?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, time-machine

Recently, my MacBook Pro 2011 unibody, 10.7.5 crashed due to bad sectors. After installing a new a hard drive, I preformed a restore via the migration assistance. It all went well except that it didn't restore to the latest date.

The cause of this is was because I had a few backups in the Timemachine that are dated far into the future, such as 2015, 2016,etc. They were made when I switched the system time to the future in order to disable some applications that were giving me problems. Right when I did this, the time machine made a backup and now those backups are always considered the "latest" backups.

So my question is, how do I preform a FULL restore using migration to a specified date, instead of what it thinks is the "latest" backup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.